# How to generate java classes from XSD using Java 11 and gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, xsd, jaxb

Java 11 has removed support for JAXB and tools like xjc which generate the java files from the XSD schema. I couldn't find many examples in Gradle for xjc generation and tried a few options but no luck so far.
Also what dependencies should one add in spring boot Gradle project to provide full support for JAXB?

Comment: Have you tried any of the [XJC plugins for Gradle](https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=xjc)?

Comment: Yes, I tried few but lastly com.github.edeandrea.xjc-generation worked for me :D, Thanks

Comment: tried com.github.edeandrea.xjc-generation because your answer @Dan and it works great! so simple to config...README is clear including what dependencies are needed and so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the correct dependencies are key to success.

```
...

    project.ext {
        jaxbTargetDir = file("src/generated/java")
    }
    
    configurations {
        xsd2java
    }
    
    dependencies {
        xsd2java "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:3.0.2"
        xsd2java "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:3.0.2"
        xsd2java "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:3.0.2"
        xsd2java "com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:2.0.1"
        xsd2java "jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.1"
    }
    
    task xsd2java() {
    
        doLast {
            jaxbTargetDir.mkdirs()
    
            ant.taskdef(name: 'xjc', classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask', classpath: configurations.xsd2java.asPath)
            ant.jaxbTargetDir = jaxbTargetDir
    
            ant.xjc(
                    destdir: '${jaxbTargetDir}',
                    package: 'dk.myproject.domain.service.request',
                    schema: 'src/build-resources/project.xsd'
            )
    
            ant.xjc(
                    destdir: '${jaxbTargetDir}',
                    package: 'dk.myproject.domain.service.response',
                    schema: 'src/build-resources/myproject.xsd'
            )
    
        }
    }
    
    compileJava.dependsOn xsd2java

...
```